# Multiple rule based expressions with 2 layer styles in Atlas

Tags: qgis, style, expression, atlas, rule-based

I have 18 transects over a geographical extent and I am applying atlas to display a map for each transect.

All is going well and I'm venturing into expressions and rule based rendering `$ID = @atlas_featureid` . 'Transect' is my coverage layer displaying individual transects (**successful so far**) without other transects bleeding into each others layouts.

However the problem arises when I try to include another layer... a point shapefile with start and end positions for each transect line.

I've tried to apply rule based rendering on the point shapefile so that the atlas displays transect with corresponding start and end positions but other start and end positions are visible in transect features (**see image below as an example**).[image: problem]
I would also like to change the symbology of start and end points and label them too but I'm confusing myself with even more rules.

Any pointers to how I can navigate my current issues and achieve handling multiple layers with multiple rule based styles and labels while using atlas?

Answer (score 2):

Transferring line ID to points and using the same rule for points: 
from processing => intersection; Input vector POINT, intersection vector LINE

[image]